# What does the "circus tent" icon mean on GitHub?

Tags: github, emoji

I'm new to GitHub and one thing that bothers me is this:

[image]

Why am I seeing this "circus tent" on my account but not on other repositories?

Comment: Because it's part of the commit message - github offers emoji icons in these messages, see for example https://scotch.io/bar-talk/emoji-icons-in-github-commit-messages

Comment: That is the default commit message used by the "Github for Windows" client when you create a new repository.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually thats part of the user commit message

For example

```
git commit -m 'Fixed whatever, time for :beers:'
```

It should appears a `:beers:` emoji

Using Reto Comments, this is the list of [emojis](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/emoji-icons-in-github-commit-messages) available.

Answer (score 4):

It is part of the commit message: an emoj '`:circus_tent:`'

you can see more emoj at [www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/).